# Can I change my application's name? The catch is that an application with the same name already exists on my account

Tags: ios, itunes-store, itunes-app

I have two applications live in the iTunes Store named A and B. Now I want to rename B to A. Is that possible? I can remove the current application A and only have B (which should use A's name) once A is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem the other day and contacted support. **You cannot use an app name that has already been used**. Even deleting the app won't help, because the name remains stored in the developer account as used. Another developer account could use it.